# Postgres: transaction isolation using a fetch size

Tags: postgresql, transactions, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

An application is connected to Postgres using jdbi (dropwizard). We can set it up to do SELECT with a given fetch size.

Ex: with a fetch size of 10 and

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100
```

It will send a single query but return the result in 10 times. There is however no difference for the developer, this is done by the driver.

My question is the following: if we do a huge query that may last few minutes, within a single transaction, will the results be based on the state of the DB at the beginning of the transaction or may it change?

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html a single transaction doesn't see changes done by other transactions (even committed ones), but if we use a fetch size, does it work the same?

Comment: The fetch size doesn't change the visibility of changes

Comment: That's an answer, thx